# How to prevent deja-dup-monitor from running, or completely delete it?

Tags: google-chrome, backup, remote-desktop, deja-dup

My ubuntu is dead after a few minutes because a process called deja-dup-monitor consumes almost 7 GB memory. I searched the internet and found that it seems to be used for backups and related to the "Chrome Remote Desktop". I don't remember installing this software and I don't want to backup something. So what commandline can I use to prevent deja-dup-monitor from running, or to completely delete it or Chrome Remote Desktop? Thanks a lot.

Comment: it's amazing that this bug is still open a year later. I was having the same problem in my ubuntu 15.10.  Just removed deja-dup.

Comment: Two years later. :) Maybe he died... who knows...

Comment: May 2019 and after an `apt update && apt upgrade` this bug hit me.  deja-dup-monitor was over 40 GiB of memory.  I do not have Chrome Remote Desktop installed.  `apt remove deja-dup solved the issue.

Answer (score 31):

I fix this problem by myself. The deja-dup-monitor is a component of "Deja Dup Backup Tool". When search with keyword "backup", this software appears blatantly in the first place in the Software Center. After uninstalling it, everything will return to order. I then reinstalled this software just to leave a review warning people not to install it, if they don't want their ubuntu to die, and uninstall it immediately in a hurry.

I am curious about the development team of this software. Does developers in this team all have a computer with 256GB memory so that no one found this problem? or they are so bold-faced to write a rubbish software to make them happy by seeing their users hit their heads against a wall. If I wrote such a code (yes I sometimes did because I'm not a genius), I will feel so ashamed that I will fix this memory leakage bug (or something) as soon as possible even after two or three sleepless nights.

Comment: There is a setup screen (when installed) under `Applications » System Tools » Preferences » Backup` -- that being said, mine was marked as being off and I could still see data being backed up. I'm not too sure where what data went... darn! I don't like that!

Answer (score 5):

Something about installing Chrome Remote Desktop causing this app to start misbehaving.  Uninstalling it as described above does the trick.

Comment: Uninstalling `deja-dup*` and `google-chrome-desktop` solves everything. I never got to make Google Remote Desktop to work anyway; my connected computers, even if both running the damn thing, are always "offline", in duplicates, or basically not available. This is one piece of crap from Google...

Answer (score 4):

There is an open bug at launchpad: [deja-dup monitor was taking 6GB of memory](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/deja-dup/+bug/1302416).

Answer (score 1):

Remove **chrome remote desktop** mine was using 3Gb of RAM, after login CPU would be zero and IOwoit would shoot too 90% and freeze every time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the mate desktop installed, there is another problem -
deja-dup is part of the desktop; and removing deja-dup removes Mate!

So, my approach is to use the mate system monitor and kill the process. Then, sudo rm /usr/bin/deja-dup.

I like to use rsync and find a mandatory installation of deja-dup preposterous.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain deja-dup for manual backups, but don't want the monitor task running, simply switch off the monitor function by clicking the button in the upper right hand corner of the deja-dup control window.

[image]

This gets rid of automatic backups and the monitor task, but allows you to take and restore backups at will.

Comment: Even when the backups are switched off (as shown in the image), there are 5 processes of deja-dup-monitor running, atleast sitting idle each with 96G or virtual memory.

Comment: same story with my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop. the backup was OFF, but deja-dup-monitor was completely stopping the system eating 140% CPU. Had to switch off the PC using power button.