# Prevent deja-dup daemon from starting, but keep deja-dup

Tags: services, deja-dup

This applies to a 16.04 Lubuntu system.

There's this related question [How to prevent deja-dup-monitor from running, or completely delete it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563143/how-to-prevent-deja-dup-monitor-from-running-or-completely-delete-it) but that user didn't use deja-dup and just wanted to kill it.  Also something about a weird interaction with Google Chrome, also not my issue.

I use deja-dup but only on demand.  I don't need its daemon running to kick off automatic backups.

I've killed the daemon and tested backups and restores with it dead and they work fine.

I tried
`sudo systemctl stop deja-dup-monitor`

but I get

`Failed to stop deja-dup-monitor.service: Unit deja-dup-monitor.service not loaded.`

though it shows up in Task Manager

[image]

Also `sudo systemctl disable deja-dup-monitor` results in

`Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory`

How can I prevent deja-dup-monitor from starting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `dpkg -S deja-dup-monitor` (or [package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=deja-dup-monitor)) its XDG desktop-autostart file is located in */etc/xdg/autostart/deja-dup-monitor.desktop* .

So you can disable `deja-dup-monitor` autostart by removing this file:

```
sudo rm /etc/xdg/autostart/deja-dup-monitor.desktop
```

As @OrganicMarble commented user-oriented solution is to launch `lxsession-edit` and uncheck *Backup Monitor*. This will create XDG-user file *~/.config/autostart/deja-dup-monitor.desktop* with contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=deja-dup
Name=Backup Monitor
Comment=Schedules backups at regular intervals
Icon=deja-dup
TryExec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/deja-dup/deja-dup-monitor
Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/deja-dup/deja-dup-monitor
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=120
StartupNotify=false
NoDisplay=true
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Archiving;
NotShowIn=LXDE;
```

The main and significant difference between this file and original */etc/xdg/autostart/deja-dup-monitor.desktop* is `NotShowIn=LXDE;` (it means that `deja-dup-monitor` will not start on LXDE session).

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna accept this because you pointed me to the answer.  While your way works perfectly, now that I know it's just autostarted, in Lubuntu, I can just open the LXsession Configuration app, click on Autostart, and untick "Backup Monitor".  That way doesn't require sudo or command lines.  Thanks again!

Comment: Updated my answer (clarified your idea). Thank you!